# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync() does not download files correctly on slow network

Tags: c#, download, webclient, downloadfileasync

My application is used to download files. After the files are downloaded, the size of those files is compared to elements in an XML file for validation. The XML file has an element for each file with a "size" attribute. This is the size that the downloaded file is supposed to be. The files validate fine on a normal Ethernet connection. When a slow wireless connection is used, files are constantly failing validation, *meaning the downloaded files are not the size they're supposed to be*. Why is it that the WebClient DownloadFileAsync() method cannot successfully download a file on a slow or unstable network? Is there any way around this besides retrying over and over?

```
foreach (var file in fileList.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, a) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OnDownloadFileCompleted());
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(AppStrings.FileServer + file.Name), AppStrings.FilePath + file.Name);
    webClientList.Add(client); //used to dispose later, after all files complete.
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code with `client.DownloadFileCompleted +=  OnDownloadFileCompleted;` ?

Comment: @I4V I don't think the event handler is the problem. It works fine as far as I can tell. The problem is that the .NET framework's WebClient.DownloadFileAsync() method is failing to download the bytes from the server correctly.

Comment: @user1172282 I doubt that all MS team have missed that point. Why don't you try it and make sure this is really not the problem?

Comment: what do you mean download bytes from server incorrectly..? looks to me like you are requesting that file be downloaded in Sorted manner since you are sorting in the foreach you are doing ` OnDownloadFileCompleted()` but like someone mentions instead of saying you don't think something is the problem why not try it and verify that  `client.DownloadFileCompleted +=  OnDownloadFileCompleted();`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I mean that the data downloaded from the server (contained in the downloaded file) does not match up with the data that the file is supposed to contain.

Comment: where and how are you populating `fileList` can you show example of incorrect output and correct output / expected output..?

Comment: I will try client.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileCompleted; and post the outcome.

Comment: I tried it and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to download too many files at once. Try to download in batches. There is also an error property on the AsyncDownloadCompleted Event object that will tell you what the exception is.